# how to visualize a javascript object onclick from a .json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I'm just starting to use javascript and json.

I need to read data (get Information function) from a json file when processing an event in a javascript function without using jquery or any other librery. I don't know if I am missing something in the code, or if I have to create an Request and handle the callback, or if I need to import additional javascript to use json. Because I don't know how to make it work. all i get is undefined. Any help is aprreciated.

The json file:

```
"hotels": [
    {
        "name": "Hotel Sunny Palms",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/sunny.jpg",
        "rating": 5,
        "price": 108.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Snowy Mountains",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/snowy.jpg",
        "rating": 4,
        "price": 120.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Windy Sails",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/windy.jpg",
        "rating": 3,
        "price": 110.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Middle of Nowhere",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/nowhere.jpg",
        "rating": 4,
        "price": 199.00
    }
]
```

my javascript is

```
function hot1(){
var text = '{"hotels": [{"name": "Hotel Sunny Palms","imgUrl": "http://www.pruebaswebludiana.xyz/imgs/sunny.jpg","rating": 5,"price": 108.00}]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("img-container").innerHTML =
obj.imagUrl+ "<br>"+ obj.name+ " " +obj.rating+ " " +obj.price;}
```

and my html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

</head>
<body>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="hot1()">Hotel Sunny Palms</li>
            <li onclick="hot2()">Hotel Snowy Mountains</li>
            <li onclick="hot3()">Hotel Windy Sails</li>
        <li onclick="hot4()">Hotel Middle Of Nowhere</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file contains an array in the property `hotels`, you probably need to work with one of those, e.g.:

```
var jsonText = ...;
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var hotels = parsedObject.hotels;
var hotel = hotels[0]; // instead of 0, pass the index of the needed hotel
document.getElementById("img-container").innerHTML = 
    hotel.imgUrl + "<br/>" + hotel.name + " " + hotel.rating + " " + hotel.price;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {"hotels": [{"name": "Hotel Sunny Palms","imgUrl": "http://www.pruebaswebludiana.xyz/imgs/sunny.jpg","rating": 5,"price": 108.00}]}
> ```

You get `undefined` because you are trying to read the `name` (and other properties) of the outer object.

The outer object doesn't have those properties. It has one property: `hotels`.

The value of the property is an array.

That array contains an object.

The properties you are trying to access exist on *that* object.

i.e.

```
obj.hotels[0].name // etc
```